# PHP PDO return a empty array the next day

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use php with PDO to manage a database with mysql. When I run the server I can read and insert data in the tables of my database, everything is correct. But, the next day I use my script, my code return a empty Array when I read and don't insert any data. Furthermore, my script don't throw any exception when does that, and I don't understand why.

I run my database connection with this code:

```
try {
   $this->dataBase = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $this->dbName . ';host=' .
                             $this->host . ';port=' . $this->port,
                             $this->user, $this->pass);

} catch (PDOException $e) { 
   echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

I get the data from my database with the code:

```
try {
   $sql = $this->dataBase->prepare("SELECT username FROM teachers");
   $sql->execute();
   $result = $sql->fetchAll();
   return $result;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
   $this->reconnect();
}
```

I do something wrong?

Comment: "SELECT username FROM teachers" doesnt look right. You are your not telling your DB what your looking for. Try something like this if you want to get all usernames: "SELECT * FROM teachers"

Comment: Did you have checked your database manually, to see if the `teachers` table is populated ? It could be empty.

Comment: I use "SELECT username FROM teachers" instead of "SELECT * FROM teachers" because I only need one field.

My table "teacher" has two rows. The day I run the server my script get perfectly the data, but the next day only return a empty array :/

Comment: Well then it seems as if your Database has a problem when your script already worked.

Comment: Maybe is possible, nevertheless when spends a day and get empty array I create a new instance of PDO class and works perfectly again. Exist a way to see mysql errors?